# SavePdfFromHtmlStreamToStream Could not get conversion result header. Data receive error. Could not receive data. Error code: 109

Tags: vb.net

Error details:
ERROR Message:
SavePdfFromHtmlStreamToStream Could not get conversion result header. Data receive error. Could not receive data. Error code: 109

```
htmlStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
        Dim _PdfConverter As PdfConverter = New PdfConverter()
        _PdfConverter.LicenseKey = "pI+VhJWVhJaclYSVlIqUhJeVipWWip2dnZ0="
        _PdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.ShowHeader = True
        _PdfConverter.PdfHeaderOptions.HeaderHeight = 20
        _PdfConverter.PdfHeaderOptions.DrawHeaderLine = False
        If (footerRequired) Then
            _PdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.ShowFooter = True
            _PdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.FooterHeight = 30
            _PdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.ShowPageNumber = True
        End If
        If OrientationMode = "Portrait" Then
            _PdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.PdfPageOrientation = PDFPageOrientation.Portrait
        Else
            _PdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.PdfPageOrientation = PDFPageOrientation.Landscape
        End If

        _PdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.PdfPageSize = PdfPageSize.A4
        Using pdfStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream

            _PdfConverter.SavePdfFromHtmlStreamToStream(htmlStream, Text.Encoding.UTF8, pdfStream)

            response.Clear()

            response.ClearContent()
            response.ClearHeaders()
            response.Buffer = True
            response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
            response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="" " + pdfFileName + """")
            pdfStream.WriteTo(response.OutputStream)
            'response.BinaryWrite(pdfStream.ToArray)
            response.[End]()
Return response
End Using
```

Comment: getting error at SavePdfFromHtmlStreamToStream method where htmlstream is memorystream and passing html code by using streamwriter write passing MemoryStream to it

Comment: Iam using ephtmltopdf 3rd party dll    --- can anyone help in solving this issue